# Converting arguments to custom objects using dataclasses package

Tags: python, object, python-datetime, python-dataclasses

I recently discovered the [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) Python package. I'm running into an issue when using custom classes in my type annotation. I've got a simple example below.

When the `Entry` class gets passed the `location` argument, the value of that argument should be used to construct a `Location` object. Similarly, when the `Entry` class gets passed a string for the `creationDate` argument, it should be parsed (using `dateutil.parser.parse`) to create a `datetime.datetime` object. In my code, the `location` and `creationDate` arguments are not converted to the `Location` and `datetime.datetime` objects. I'm not sure how to make this work. **Please advise.**

Granted, I could do this without using the dataclasses package. It would add more boilerplate code. I'm also using this as an excuse to learn the dataclasses package so I can use it more efficiently the next time.

[Try it](https://www.online-python.com/jhJE7vDsxT)

```py
import datetime
import dateutil.parser
import dataclasses
import inspect

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Location():
    latitude: float
    longitude: float

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Entry():
    """
    A single DayOne entry
    """
    creationDate: datetime.datetime = \
        dataclasses.field(default_factory=dateutil.parser.parse)
    location: Location = None

    @classmethod
    def factory(cls, **kwargs):
        class_fields = {k:v for k,v in kwargs.items()
                        if k in inspect.signature(cls).parameters}

        return cls(**class_fields)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Converting from dayone to jekyll\n")


    args = {
        "creationDate": '2022-05-30T04:44:33Z',
        "location": {
            'latitude': -37.8721,
            'longitude': 175.6829,
            'named': 'Hobbiton'
        },
        "text": "In a hole in the ground there lived a hobbit. Not a nasty, dirty, wet hole, filled with the ends of worms and an oozy smell, nor yet a dry, bare, sandy hole with nothing in it to sit down on or to eat: it was a hobbit-hole, and that means comfort."
    }

    entry = Entry.factory(**args)
    print(type(entry.location))
    print(type(entry.creationDate))
```

Comment: Could you not use pydantic to more directly achieve your goal? (https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/)

Comment: @Ricibob Perhaps. (I didn't know about pydantic.) What I've shown in my question is a *minimal* example. I'm going to do more than just convert the arguments. However, I need to have the arguments converted before I can do anything else.

Comment: I would prefer to limit the number of third-party packages that I have to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be to use [dataclass-wizard](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/), which is a bit more lightweight than `pydantic`. It uses `typing-extensions` module for earlier python versions, but in 3.10+ it only relies on core python stdlib.

Usage:

```py
from __future__ import annotations  # can be removed in 3.10+

import datetime
# import dateutil.parser
import dataclasses
from pprint import pprint

from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Location:
    latitude: float
    longitude: float
    named: str | None = None


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Entry(JSONWizard):
    """
    A single DayOne entry
    """
    creation_date: datetime.datetime
    location: Location | None = None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Converting from dayone to jekyll\n")

    args = {
        "creationDate": '2022-05-30T04:44:33Z',
        "location": {
            'latitude': -37.8721,
            'longitude': 175.6829,
            'named': 'Hobbiton'
        },
        "text": "In a hole in the ground there lived a hobbit. Not a nasty, dirty, wet hole, filled with the ends of worms and an oozy smell, nor yet a dry, bare, sandy hole with nothing in it to sit down on or to eat: it was a hobbit-hole, and that means comfort."
    }

    entry = Entry.from_dict(args)
    print(type(entry.location))
    print(type(entry.creation_date))
    print()

    print('Object:')
    pprint(entry)
```

Result:

```
Converting from dayone to jekyll

<class '__main__.Location'>
<class 'datetime.datetime'>

Object:
Entry(creation_date=datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 30, 4, 44, 33, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
      location=Location(latitude=-37.8721, longitude=175.6829, named='Hobbiton'))
```

---

**Side note**: I haven't actually thought of using `dateutil.parser.parse` to parse date strings, though that might be a good idea coinidentally. The current implementation uses `datetime.fromisoformat` which does work well enough in the general use case.

Comment: This works well, although I have one question. `args` has a key called `creationDate`. This is converted to `creation_date` using `JSONWizard.from_dict`. Can someone explain how this magic works?

Comment: @jlconlin apologies, I might have forgot to respond, but will attempt to do so now. the `dataclass-wizard` library uses a regex approach to case transform JSON keys that don't directly map to dataclass fields (and which aren't already lower-cased) to a valid *snake case* format. It essentially uses a helper function [`to_snake_case`](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dataclass_wizard.utils.html?highlight=to_snake_case#dataclass_wizard.utils.string_conv.to_snake_case), which converts keys in other casing to snake cased strings by default, and then maps it to a known field.

Comment: Note that I'm thinking about switching to a non-regex approach using [`pyheck`](https://pypi.org/project/pyheck/) or similar, which is implemented in Rust and then ported to Python code using the `pyo3` library, as it should be overall faster, and also addresses a few edge cases which I've noticed the regex implementation doesn't handle as desired, such as strings with punctuation like `this. is @? a*test!` for example.